# Correct way of binding multiple attribute changes to a Backbone.js model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model

I have the following code, where I bind a change to a single attribute "attribute_1".

```
var Mine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.bind("change:attribute_1", function() {
      console.log('changed!');
    });
  }
});
```

How do I bind two attributes? This doesn't work:

```
var Mine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.bind("change:attribute_1, change:attribute_2", function() {
      console.log('changed!');
    });
  }
});
```

Nor does this:

```
var Mine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.bind("change:attribute_1 change:attribute_2", function() {
      console.log('changed!');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know if such a "bulk-bind" function exists (you could open a feature request for it, it seems useful).

You can bind them separately:

```
var Mine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var listener = function() { console.log('changed'); };
    this.bind("change:attribute_1", listener);
    this.bind("change:attribute_2", listener);
  }
});
```

Or you can listen to all changes (and then filter in the listener):

```
var Mine = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var listener = function() { console.log('changed'); };
    this.bind("change", listener);
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, `bind()` is chainable: `this.bind(...).bind(...)`.

Comment: If using a common listener, how do you check which attribute changed?

Answer (score 81):

As of Backbone.js 0.9.0, the `bind()` function (which has been [renamed to `on()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on)) supports a space-delimited list of events:

```
model.on("change:title change:author", ...)

// equivalent to

model.bind("change:title change:author", ...)
```

Comment: Now does this call the callback once or multiple times per change?

Comment: @Sukima It calls once per changed attribute. If title changes, fires once. If author changes, fires once. If both title and author change, first once for title and once for author.

Comment: How does this map to the listenTo syntax?

Comment: @backdesk it would be the same `model.listenTo(model, "change:title change:author", ...)`